# Inputting non-array elements in a method which receives an array

Tags: arrays, methods, parameters

Let's assume I have 3 integers a, b and c which are not in an array. Now I have a method which accepts an array of integers. Can this be done without creating an array before the input arguments? My reasoning may be better explained in my following attempt:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 6;
int c = 1;

methodName( {a, b, c} );
..
static int methodName(int[] nums){..}
```

This does not work as it the compiler gives a syntax error at the input parameters. The reason I coded the input as "{a, b, c}" is because it is correct to initialize an array as:

```
int[] nums = {3, 6, 1};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible in languages such as c, but you can implement this in some weak typing language such as python

```
def displayList(myList):
    for e in myList:
        print(e)

def main():
    a=1
    b=2
    c=3
    displayList([a,b,c])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not goanna work because you should to mention type of array

In java provide feature like `...`

Try this:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 6;
int c = 1;
int d = 2;

methodName( a, b, c , d );

static int methodName(int .. nums){..}
```

Now you can  get value from nums as array  `nums[index]`